# Animate Screen Switch Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Right now, I am trying to create a basic workout app. I am working on the play workout feature, and have one thing I want to change that I have no idea how to do. When the user clicks the next arrow, I want to make the next workout slide in instead of just being replaced, because it looks cooler. I tried to do it but the way I am programming the exercises makes it a bit hard to do. I really need your help. Thanks!

Here is the exercises array:

```
 List<Map<String, dynamic>> workoutMap = [
    {
      'plan_name': 'My First Plan',
      'content': [
        {
          'name': 'My First Workout',
          'exercises': [
            {
              'name': 'Bicep Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Preacher Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '3',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Bicep Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '7',
              'reps': '12',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Preacher Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '15',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Bicep Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': 'NA',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Preacher Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Bicep Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Preacher Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'plan_name': 'My Second Plan',
      'content': [
        {
          'name': 'My Second Workout',
          'exercises': [
            {
              'name': '#2 Bicep Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Preacher Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '3',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Bicep Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '7',
              'reps': '12',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Preacher Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '15',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Bicep Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': 'NA',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Preacher Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Bicep Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            },
            {
              'name': 'Preacher Curl',
              'musclesworked': ['bicep', 'tricep'],
              'sets': '5',
              'reps': '10',
              'weight': '11',
              'video':
                  'https://thumbs.gfycat.com/MistyMisguidedIzuthrush-size_restricted.gif'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ];
```

and here is my code

```
class BlackScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> exercises;
  BlackScreen({Key? key, required this.exercises}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BlackScreenState createState() => _BlackScreenState();
}

class _BlackScreenState extends State<BlackScreen> {
  int currentExerciseIndex = 0;
  bool isPaused = false;
  int elapsedTime = 0; // time elapsed for an exercise

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
  }

  void startTimer() async {
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      if (isPaused) continue;

      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          elapsedTime++;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  void pauseTimer() {
    setState(() {
      isPaused = !isPaused;
    });
  }

  void previousExercise() {
    if (currentExerciseIndex > 0) {
      setState(() {
        currentExerciseIndex--;
        elapsedTime = 0;
        isPaused = false;
      });
    }
  }

  String formatDuration(int seconds) {
    final minutes = (seconds / 60).floor().toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final remainingSeconds = (seconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return '$minutes:$remainingSeconds';
  }

  Widget buildButton(IconData iconData, onPressed, double size) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: Container(
        height: 50, // provide the height you want for the buttons
        width: 50, // provide the width you want for the buttons
        child: iconData == Icons.play_arrow || iconData == Icons.pause
            ? Container(
                height: size, // provide the height you want for the buttons
                width: size, // provide the width you want for the buttons
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xff11b779),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: Icon(
                  iconData,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  size: size - 10,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              )
            : Icon(
                iconData,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: size,
              ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  var totalTime = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    var topPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;

    // Do nothing if there's no exercises
    if (widget.exercises.length == 0) return Container();

    // Show the current exercise name
    return Container(
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.center, children: [
          Positioned(
              top: 0,
              child: Image.network(
                  widget.exercises[currentExerciseIndex]['video'],
                  height: size.height * .7)),
          Positioned(
              top: topPadding + 10,
              left: 10,
              child: Row(children: [
                GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                        size: 20, color: Colors.black)),
                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                  child: Text('Just Lift'),
                ),
              ])),
          Positioned(
            top: topPadding + 12,
            right: 10,
            child: DefaultTextStyle(
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
              child: Text('Exercise ' +
                  (currentExerciseIndex + 1).toString() +
                  '/' +
                  (widget.exercises.length).toString()),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
              top: size.height * .7 + 10,
              child: Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    DefaultTextStyle(
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 25,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      child: Text(widget.exercises[currentExerciseIndex]['name']
                          .toUpperCase()),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Text('${formatDuration(elapsedTime)}',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25)),
                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        buildButton(
                          Icons.arrow_back,
                          currentExerciseIndex == 0 ? null : previousExercise,
                          size.height * .05,
                        ),
                        buildButton(
                          isPaused ? Icons.play_arrow : Icons.pause,
                          pauseTimer,
                          size.height * .07,
                        ),
                        buildButton(
                          Icons.arrow_forward,
                          currentExerciseIndex == widget.exercises.length - 1
                              ? null
                              : nextExercise,
                          size.height * .05,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ]))),
          currentExerciseIndex == widget.exercises.length - 1
              ? Positioned(
                  bottom: 2,
                  width: size.width * .33,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => {nextExercise()},
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 17, 183, 183),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                          tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap),
                      child: Text('Finish!',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))))
              : Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    DefaultTextStyle(
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      child: Transform.translate(
                          offset: Offset(-3, 0), child: Text(' Up Next')),
                    ),
                    DefaultTextStyle(
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 209, 209, 209),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      child: Text(
                          widget.exercises[currentExerciseIndex + 1]['name']),
                    )
                  ]))
        ]));
  }

  void nextExercise() {
    // Increase the index, or go back if this is the last exercise
    if (currentExerciseIndex < widget.exercises.length - 1) {
      totalTime += elapsedTime;
      setState(() {
        currentExerciseIndex++;
        elapsedTime = 0;
        isPaused = false;
      });
    } else {
      totalTime += elapsedTime;
      print(totalTime);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the `AnimatedSwitcher` widget:

- https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html

This will implicitly animate every time you replace its child. Since you'll probably be using the same type of widget as it's child, with the exception of perhaps your "finish!" widget, you'll need to make sure to set the `key` for your child widgets.

The `AnimatedSwitcher` widget was featured as a widget of the week on Flutter's youtube channel, so there's a great little intro video on how to use it on the documentation page.

Comment: I tried it and added this code in the return statement AnimatedSwitcher(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        key: ValueKey(currentExerciseIndex),
        child: MYCHILD), but that didn't animate it when I click the next button. Am I doing it right? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you've put the key in your `AnimatedSwitcher`, but you should be assigning the key to your child widget.

Comment: The code sample for `AnimatedSwitcher` provides a great example of how to use the key: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html#widgets.AnimatedSwitcher.1